# Replicate a shared database on Cloudant

Tags: database, replication, cloudant

I'm trying to replicate the DB that was shared with me (owner/sharedDB) to my db (dybskiy/copyOfSharedDB) via Futon Replicator. I get the following error:

> Replication failed: could not open http://me.cloudant.com:5984/owner%2FsharedDB/

How shall I do it?

Comment: did you supply the right username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make replication of a shared database work from the Futon interface, enter the full url of the shared database in the `Remote DB` field, like this:

```
https://[username]:[password]@[shared_username].cloudant.com/[database]
```

To replicate a shared database via `curl`, you'll have to explicitly set the SOURCE and TARGET parameters in the replication request, with your username and password for authentication, like so:

```
SOURCE="https://[username]:[password]@[shared_username].cloudant.com/"
TARGET="https://[username]:[password]@[username].cloudant.com/"
DB_TO_REPLICATE="fakedatabase"
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"source":"$SOURCE$DB_TO_REPLICATE","target":"$TARGET$DB_TO_REPLICATE"}' $TARGET\_replicate
```